# Absolute Footer not sticking to bottom of page, mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, footer

Okay so i have looked at a bunch of the other questions on this site regarding sticky footers and have tried heaps of them to get them working on mobile but to no avail (desktop is fine). I am running buddypress on my site so the html is generated through that, here is what it looks like at the moment. I added a green background to make it more clear.

[Mobile Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRYp2.png)

Here is my css for the buddypress container and footer. There is absolute positioning on the container and footer while the divs inside (header, nav, and body) are all relative.

```
#buddypress{
  width:100%; /* Add this */
  height:100%;
  max-width: 480px;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  position: absolute;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  background:black;
  color:white;
}
.x-colophon.bottom {
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

#buddypress #item-header{
background-color: rgba(49,175,145,1);
border: none;
width: 100%;
left: 0;
right: 0;
position: relative;

}

#item-nav {
background-color: white;
font-size: 16px;
width: 100%;
position: relative;
}

#item-body {
background-color: white;
color: black;
width: 100%;
position: relative;
}
```

Comment: show a demo for us

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your footer -

```
.footer {
        position: relative;
        bottom:  -500px; // you can adjust the negative value
    }
```